# Comparing time ranges in javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, datetime

I need to validate time picked by user, start date must be greater than 6 am and smaller than end date which must not exceed next day 2 am.

though I dont have date as an input I assume I should append dates to the picked times to compare, is this the best way to achieve it or there is a smarter one ?

here is what I can think of so far

```
function compareTimes(start,end){
    var t1 = new date();
    var t2 = new date();

    var starttime = t1 + " " + start;
    if (end >= '00:00'){
        t2.setDate(t2.getDate()+1);
    } 
    var endtime = t2 + " " + end;
    if(Date.parse ( endtime ) > Date.parse ( starttime )){
        alert ("greater than");
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: show us the code you tried

Comment: What’s in the `start` and `end` parameters?  It looks to be a string, formatted as `HH:nn`, but is it guaranteed to be that?

Comment: @Martijn yes exactly as you said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function appends a time string like the one you give, to a date, and returns that as a new Date object. If you pass no date, it will use today’s date.

```
function setDateTime(timeString, date) {
    var result = (date ? new Date(date) : new Date())
    ,   match = /(\d+):(\d+)/.exec(timeString)
    ;
    result.setHours(Number(match[1]), Number(match[2]), 0, 0);
    return result;
}
```

Once you’ve got your `startDate = setDateTime(start);` and your `endDate = setDateTime(end);`,  you can then use the [getHours](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours) method to figure out if it’s before or after 2 am or 6 pm.

N.B. you should probably check if the hour < 6, and it so, add a day to it (`endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 1);`, otherwise your end date will be before your start date.  :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot, thats what I had in mind but didnt know how to implement it

Answer (score 1):

Try this library. Differency function should work for you.
http://momentjs.com

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I'll have to void libraries (the page is already loaded)

Comment: @Digitalfortress: I take it you mean to **avoid** libraries... :-) But what does it matter whether the page is already loaded?  You can add the library, and reload the page, no?

Comment: Sorry for the typo :) Well, this is the clients' opinion!!

Comment: @Digitalfortress: Wait, what? The client decides what libraries you get to use, and which libraries you don’t?